# Add option selected disabled in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a form with a dropdown field in PHP with this array:

```
$field["options"] = array(
     array("value" => "Chişinău", "text" => "Chişinău", "depth" => 0),
     array("value" => "Bălţi", "text" => "Bălţi", "depth" => 0),
     array("value" => "Comrat", "text" => "Comrat", "depth" => 0),
     ...
     array("value" => "Ungheni", "text" => "Ungheni", "depth" => 0)
);
```

How to add as a first option the `<option selected disabled>Choose one</option>`?

Comment: Tried `array("value" => "Chişinău", "text" => "Chişinău", "depth" => 0, "selected" => "selected", "disabled" => "disabled"),
`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$field["options"] = array(
    array("value" => " ", "text" => "Choose one", "depth" => 0, "selected" => "selected", "disabled" => "disabled"),
    //...rest other option code
);
```