# Add option selected disabled to a dynamic form field in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

Recently I already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739380/add-option-selected-disabled-in-php), but now my form is a dynamical one, so the code is not a similar one as in the previous question and I have some difficulties to solve my problem.

I have a code that adds some options to a form with a dropdown "Category" field where categories are collected dynamically. What I want is to add as a first option of that field the `<option selected disabled>Select a category ...</option>` in a PHP specific way.

My actual code:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if($form["field"][$i]["name"] == "advert_category") {
        $form["field"][$i]["max_choices"] = 1;
        // This is what I tried
        //$form["field"][$i]["options"] = array(array("value" => " ", "text" => "Select a category ...", "depth" => 0, "selected" => "selected", "disabled" => "disabled"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// append
$form["field"][$i]["options"][] = array("value" => " ", "text" => "Select a category ...", "depth" => 0, "selected" => "selected", "disabled" => "disabled");
// or prepend 
array_unshift($form["field"][$i]["options"], array("value" => " ", "text" => "Select a category ...", "depth" => 0, "selected" => "selected", "disabled" => "disabled"));
```