# Dealing with starting index in array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, html-select

I've got an array of users from a database (I'm working in PHP, using CodeIgniter in Sublime)

I've got a view, that has a select that show display all the users, so in my view, at the top, I have this code (suppose that the arrays has 3 items):

```
<?php
$optionsUsers = array();

$qtyUsers = count($users);  -->

if($qtyUsers > 0){
    $optionsUsers[0]['name'] = 'Choose an option';
    for($i=0; $i < $qtyUsers; $i++){
        $optionsUsers[$i]['id'] = $users[$i]["userId"];
        $optionsUsers[$i]['name'] = $users[$i]["username"];
    }
}
?>
```

Then, in the select part, I have this:

```
 <select id="cursadaUsuario">
        <?php
        $qtyOptionsUsers = count($optionsUsers);
        if($qtyOptionsUsers>0){
          for($i=0; $i<$qtyOptionsUsers; $i++){
             if($i == 0){
                echo '<option value="0" disabled selected>Please select an option</option>';
             }else{
                echo '<option value="'.$optionsUsers[$i]['id'].'">'.$optionsUsers[$i]['name'].'</option>';
             }
           }
         }else{
             echo '<option value="">There are no options available</option>';   
         }
         ?>
 </select>
```

I've assigned to the $optionsUsers array in [0] the string "Choose an option" because when iterating THAT ARRAY in the select, I wanted to display it as disabled and just iterate the rest of the elements as usual

The problem is that array $users starts in 0 --> I've checked it with a foreach and all the users display are actually there:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value){
      print_r($users);
   });
```

But I wanted [0] to be the text to display, "Choose your option", so if I assign the text to [0], the first item in array $users is never shown :( (in this example, it would iterate the text and 2 of the items, not the 3)

If I remove the text to [O], and just iterate the array, all the users are shown correctly, no one is missing, but that means... no text to tell "Choose an option" :/

I would like it to look like this --> http://www.hkvstore.com/phpreportmaker/doc/images/dropdownselect.png, so I want the text "Choose you option" to be shown AND disabled, and then the elements of the array, in my case, a list of users.

Note: I would like to keep using a 'for' loop.
Note2: This ([Add option selected disabled in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739380/add-option-selected-disabled-in-php)) would be kind of similar to what I want to achieve, but still, I don't think I could just change the keys and assign my own to a list of users, the could be changed, added, deleted, etc.. :/

Ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm not understanding you, it's the same as the "No options available" option – it belongs outside the loop:

```
if ($qtyOptionsUsers > 0) {
  echo '<option value="0" disabled selected>Please select an option</option>';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $qtyOptionsUsers; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="'.$optionsUsers[$i]['id'].'">'.$optionsUsers[$i]['name'].'</option>';
  }
} else {
  echo '<option value="">There are no options available</option>';   
}
```

Comment: Ohhh yes! Thank you so much! How did I not see that!? xD Thank youu! Exactly what I wanted! :D

Answer (score 1):

you need to push the users data from index 1 rather than from 0 index.Try below code to fix the choose option

```
for($i=0; $i <= $qtyUsers; $i++){
   $optionsUsers[$i+1]['id'] = $users[$i]["userId"];
   $optionsUsers[$i+1]['name'] = $users[$i]["username"];
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I've actually chose the previous answer, but I'll test yours too just out of curiosity haha, I haven't thought it that way! :o